# Symfony 2.0 session locale not set from URL?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm creating a web page URL for an external application to access, like: `http://my.site/en/page/1` or 
 `http://my.site/fr/page/1`. In Twig template, I'm using `app.session.locale` variable.

`app.session.locale` work fine, but `url()` and `path()` functions sometimes randomly use default locale - they generate /en/ URLs instead of /fr/ on a /fr/ page. This doesn't reproduce in a stable way.

Adding `_locale` parameter like `url('_foobar_action', {'something': model.fooId, '_locale': app.session.locale} )` doesn't help. This sounds like this [discussion which](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/23lvS2dBZYU) is no good news.

There is no session in the external application that acessess this URL, it's safe to consider it to be `wget`.

What can be wrong here? Is it a known problem?

Comment: There was a major change committed today in the master branch. You may want to check it out even though you're on 2.0. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/4692

Comment: Thanks @MDrollette! Can you please repost this as an answer? :)
Not sure that I'd risk upgrading to 2.1, and it's not in 2.0 8(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a major change committed today in the master branch. You may want to check it out even though you're on 2.0. http://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/4692